# [linphone-android]working all emulator but stopped working my real device 4.4.2

Tags: java, android, linphone

i'm building linphone-android app i'm tested emulator generating apk all work fine but i'm tested on my real device Android 4.4.2 Stopped working and this logcat

```
04-11 18:28:57.645 22384-22384/org.linphone W/dalvikvm: JNI WARNING: received null jstring (GetStringUTFChars)
04-11 18:28:57.645 22384-22384/org.linphone W/dalvikvm:              in Lorg/linphone/core/LinphoneFriendImpl;.setName:(JLjava/lang/String;)V (GetStringUTFChars)
04-11 18:28:57.645 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
04-11 18:28:57.645 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41609e58 self=0x415299f0
04-11 18:28:57.645 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=22384 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074438484
04-11 18:28:57.645 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 899376799 405274548 3029 ) utm=55 stm=34 core=0
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #00  pc 0000132e  /system/lib/libcorkscrew.so (unwind_backtrace_thread+29)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #01  pc 00063506  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpNativeStack(DebugOutputTarget const*, int)+33)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #02  pc 000574ec  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThreadEx(DebugOutputTarget const*, Thread*, bool)+395)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #03  pc 0005755a  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDumpThread(Thread*, bool)+25)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #04  pc 0003b65c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #05  pc 0003b944  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #06  pc 0003c964  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #07  pc 0003ed74  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #08  pc 002d6d90  /data/app-lib/org.linphone-1/liblinphone-armeabi-v7a.so (Java_org_linphone_core_LinphoneFriendImpl_setName+32)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #09  pc 0002034c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #10  pc 00050fce  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+397)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #11  pc 000297e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #12  pc 00030c6c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #13  pc 0002e304  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #14  pc 00063718  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+391)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #15  pc 0006b61e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #16  pc 000297e0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #17  pc 00030c6c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #18  pc 0002e304  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #19  pc 00063434  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+335)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #20  pc 0004cbb6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #21  pc 0004d3bc  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #22  pc 0004e1aa  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+353)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #23  pc 0000105a  /system/bin/app_process
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:   #24  pc 0000e498  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+47)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm: at org.linphone.core.LinphoneFriendImpl.setName(Native Method)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm: at org.linphone.core.LinphoneFriendImpl.setName(LinphoneFriendImpl.java:129)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at org.linphone.LinphoneContact.refresh(LinphoneContact.java:394)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at org.linphone.ContactsManager.fetchContactsAsync(ContactsManager.java:246)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at org.linphone.ContactsManager.fetchContacts(ContactsManager.java:203)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at org.linphone.LinphoneActivity.onResume(LinphoneActivity.java:1239)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5310)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2820)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2253)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
04-11 18:28:57.675 22384-22384/org.linphone A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00005770 (code=-6), thread 22384 (org.linphone)
```

read some stackoverflow question about this some people say this bug on 4.4.2 Version android but i tested Linphone Play Store App on my device work well.

Answer (score 0):

what version is the emulator?
If its a real difference between both version it should  be a backguard compatibility problem

Comment: Problem on 4.4.2 Real Device All Emulator version work well